# Action Script 3.0. How to detect key combinations (keys clicked in row)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, keyboard, key

I'm creating flash game.

By clicking "z" key It starts attack1 animation.

By clicking "x" key It starts attack2 animation.

By clicking "c" key It starts attack3 animation.

I need something like that:

By clicking keys combination It should start attack4 (special attack) animation.

By clicking "z" key, after It "x", after It "c" key (z > x > c) - It should start attack4 animation.

Structure should be something like that:

```
keyDown z
keyUp z
delay ~250 milliseconds 
keyDown right_arrow
keyUp right_arrow
delay ~250 milliseconds 
keyDown x
keyUpx
start attack3 animation
```

For now my code is:

```
        private function key_down(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 90)
            {
            Hero.gotoAndStop("attack1");
            }
}
        private function key_up(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
                if (event.keyCode == 90)
                {
                 Hero.gotoAndStop("stay");
                }
```

}

Have you ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : http://www.actiontad.com/components/src/com/tadSrc/arcade/ASJSComboKeys.html - used it in a project long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create an array and push the keycode into the array each time a key is pressed and use some sort of timer to make the delays. Then each time a key is pressed check the array, if too much time between keypresses has passed then clean the array.

PD: you may use a counter in an enter frame event instead of a timer if you dont know how to use timers

Comment: Thank you for answer, could you write me example code how should It look like?